# How to assign sorted array to itself again?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[] myarray = { 32, 55, 2, 1, 45, 1532, 32, 66, 54, 32 };       
myarray = Array.Sort(myarray);
```

throws Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int[]'

How can I do this?

Comment: Use just `Array.Sort(myarray);`. The `Array.Sort` method doesn't return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.Sort is the void method and not return value:

```
public static void Sort(
    Array keys,
    Array items
)
```

but sort the array

```
Array.Sort(myarray); // sort the array value
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign `myarray` just go with `Array.Sort(myarray);`

Answer (score 1):

[Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not return a value so you need to try simply this:

```
int[] myarray = { 32, 55, 2, 1, 45, 1532, 32, 66, 54, 32 };       
Array.Sort(myarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Array.Sort(myarray) doesn't return value.

Solution1:

```
Array.Sort(myarray);
```

Solution 2:Change type of your method

```
public int[] Sort(int[] arr){
...
return arr;
}
```